# htmlhelper in mvc custom validationsummary get value

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, helper

I want to get the Model property value 
My ViewModel is a List of models.

I dont know how to ask the helper object.
in run time I can see the value in `helper.ViewData.Model.ModelEntity[0].phoneNumber`
but no code for this.

```
public static MvcHtmlString GanimValidationSummary<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, string validationMessage = "")
{
    string retVal = "";
    if (helper.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
        return null;  
    foreach (var key in helper.ViewData.ModelState.Keys)
    {  
        foreach (var err in helper.ViewData.ModelState[key].Errors)
        {
              retVal += helper.Encode(err.ErrorMessage) + "<br />";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unclear what your asking. What are you trying to do with this extension method?

Comment: this is the validation message for the user, just want to add to the message the value of the model, like this  retVal += helper.Encode(err.ErrorMessage) + helper.ViewData.Model.ModelEntity[0].phoneNumber

Comment: What is wrong with using the inbuilt `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)` and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` methods?

Comment: Because I"m using list of models in one view,  and I want notice the user which model is refer to.

Comment: Then use `@Html.ValidationMesageFor()` associated with each property in the model (as I told you in your last question)

Comment: I need to show the message in the top of the page, not under each input

Comment: The code you have shown wont do that (and your method does not even return anything so it wont actually show anything at all).

Comment: I just want to get the value from the model

Comment: Study [the source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/ValidationExtensions.cs)

Comment: Thanks alot  Stephen